# R Shiny: Updating proxy table column headers in ObserveEvent

Tags: shiny, reactive, dt

I would like to update column headers in an R Shiny proxy table. The app should:

1. Launch with original column header names (e.g. "Do","Re","Mi","Fa","So")
2. Change those column headers in the proxy table to something else when the user clicks an action button (e.g. "y1","y2","y3","y4","y5")

Shiny has a convenient updateCaption() method that allows for a similar behavior for proxy table captions. I'd like to do something similar with table column headers for proxy tables. Here's my attempt.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    actionButton(
      "updatebutton",
      label = "Update Table",
      style = "margin-right: 5px;"
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myplot")
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  mycolumnnames <-c("Do","Re","Mi","Fa","So")
  myothercolumnnames <- c("y1","y2","y3","y4","y5")
  output$myplot <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DF <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(rnorm(5), 10, rep = TRUE)))
    datatable(DF, colnames = mycolumnnames,
              caption="Original caption")
  })

  proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("myplot")

  observeEvent(input$updatebutton, {
    updateCaption(proxy, caption="Look, I am a NEW caption!")
    DF <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(rnorm(5), 10, rep = TRUE)))
    # names(DF) <- myothercolumnnames # This doesn't work
    proxy %>% replaceData(DF)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit1: Now uses `dataTableProxy()`

I took away all the things related to color background so I could focus on your problem.

First, I declare some values outside shiny: your data.frame and two vectors for the column names. Then I assign the column names as the first vector.

Inside the app, I retrieve the data as a `reactiveVal()`, and update its `colnames` whenever the button is pressed

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mycolumnnames <-c("Do","Re","Mi","Fa","So")
myothercolumnnames <- c("y1","y2","y3","y4","y5")
DF <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(rnorm(5), 10, rep = TRUE)))
colnames(DF) <- mycolumnnames

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    actionButton(
      "updatebutton",
      label = "Update Table",
      style = "margin-right: 5px;"
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myplot")
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(DF)
  
  output$myplot <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(df(), caption="Original caption")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$updatebutton, {
    new_data <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(rnorm(5), 10, rep = TRUE)))
    
    if(!input$updatebutton %% 2 == 0 ){
      colnames(new_data) <- myothercolumnnames
    } else {
      colnames(new_data) <- mycolumnnames 
    }
    df(new_data)
    proxy1 <- DT::dataTableProxy("myplot")
    updateCaption(proxy1, caption="Look, I am a NEW caption!")
    replaceData(proxy1, df())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So whenever you press the button, the colnames are changed between the two vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Pabort. I followed your lead and revised the example code in the question to focus on the problem. As for your solution, it won't work for my application because I need to replace the data using replaceData() + proxy table. Unless there's a way to make the column headers reactive so that the proxy table updates them when replaceData is called?

Comment: I changed my answer to work with replaceData() and a proxy table.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for your help, Pabort. I marked your response as the accepted answer. I also tried to upvote it but I don't have the requisite 15 "reputation points" to do so.